# how to get users daily average time in pandas ,start time and end time

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**I have two tables need to merge two tables and get login time and logout time and average time of user**`

> table name : AllLogin

```
id   login_date    login_time   user_id 

1   2021-12-29  21:45:42.061506    4
2   2021-12-30  15:47:56.740154    2
3   2021-12-30  19:50:20.742582    4
4   2021-12-30  19:55:41.187090    1
5   2022-01-03  17:31:53.078602    1
6   2022-01-03  17:32:31.224342    2
7   2022-01-03  19:12:03.104795    4
8   2022-01-04  15:40:22.111702    1
9   2022-01-05  16:07:42.412031    2
10  2022-01-05  16:07:57.733591    2
11  2022-01-05  16:08:31.979159    1
```

> table name : AllLogout

```
id   logout_date    logout_time   user_id 
1   2022-01-06  14:51:14.752459     1
2   2022-01-06  14:51:59.060639     2
3   2022-01-10  13:48:54.729281     2
4   2022-01-10  14:04:54.520387     2
5   2022-01-10  14:05:31.098456     2
```

How to combine two tables and count everyday users average time,
user loggin multiple times and logout also multiple time i need each day average time of user
`

code ::

```
    queryset=AllLogin.objects.values('login_time')
    querySet3 = AllLogout.objects.values('logout_time')
  
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(queryset, columns = ['login_time','user'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(querySet3, columns = ['logout_time','user'])
    # print(df1,df2)
    # df_row = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
    df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True),df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
    # means = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D')).mean()

    df_row_reindex = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

    df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['user']).set_index(['logout_time','user']).sum(axis=1)
    # df = (pd.to_datetime(df.logout_time) - pd.to_datetime(df.login_time)).dt.total_seconds()
    
    '''changed'''

    df['AllLogin_flag'] = 'AllLogin'
    df['AllLogout_flag'] = 'AllLogout'
    logout =df.rename(columns={'logout_date':'login_date','logout_time':'login_time'})
    # login1 = login.append(logout, ignore_index=True)
    # login1  = login1.sort_values(by=['user_id', 'login_date','login_time'])
```

Comment: post your data as dataframe constructor, for example `df = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": [1, 2, 3, etc..]})`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in following ways :
Step 1 : Create Flag in each data for login and logout

```
login['flag'] = 'login'
logout['flag'] = 'logout'
```

Step 2 : Rename logout date and time

```
logout =logout.rename(columns={'logout_date':'login_date','logout_time':'login_time'})
```

Step 3 : Concatenate in one dataframe

```
login1 = login.append(logout, ignore_index=True)
```

Step 4 : Sort Values by user id , date and time

```
login1  = login1.sort_values(by=['user_id', 'login_date','login_time'])
login1.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Step 5 : Create Shift variables, assumption once a user login we will have a logout time so shift will bring them in one row

```
login1['shift_user_id'] = login1['user_id'].shift(-1)
login1['shift_flag'] = login1['flag'].shift(-1)
login1['shift_login_time'] = login1['login_time'].shift(-1)
```

The ouput of this look like this :[image]

Now just keep those records where user == shift user id and flag = login and shift flag = logout, tak diff of actual time and shift time and group by date and apply average on diff. This should work

Comment: Please share code for more reference..

Comment: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: please look at once ,code